# How to use vanilla JS files from a React Native project?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm able to import a vanilla.js file to my React Native project with `import './vanilla';`

When I try to use anything in that file, it just says `Can't find variable`. I know the import is succesful because if I put `window.something` into the vanilla file, I can call `something`. So I guess the question is how do I get visibility into the variables, functions, etc. that I imported from the vanilla file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
import vanilla from './vanilla';
```

then you can use your exported functions, ie:

```
vanilla.someMethod();
```

Check out: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: how you are exporting? Could you please provider an example?

Comment: This is one of the libraries that I've been trying to work with: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/sjcl.js

Comment: No problem @AtteJuvonen!

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty much depends on how do you export your module?
You have multiple options to export your module or functions of that module.

For example:

```
// export data
export var color = "red";
export let name = "Nicholas";
export const magicNumber = 7;

// export function
export function sum(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num1;
}

// export class
export class Rectangle {
    constructor(length, width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
}

// this function is private to the module
function subtract(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

// define a function...
function multiply(num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}

// ...and then export it later
export { multiply };
```

or exporting a default value such as:

```
function sum(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

export default sum;
```

you can read more about exporting and importing modules here: https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read/#leanpub-auto-basic-exporting

Comment: I wanted to use a crypto library without modifying it. Is this possible with React Native? For example, is there a way to import this library without modifying it: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/sjcl.js

Comment: It would be nice if you add some examples how to import each option of your example